# Formatting tablenotes

Tags: formatting, threeparttable, tablenotes

I always have issues with the formatting of my tablenotes, and tend to settle on something that is "okay." However, I cannot find an "okay" point here.

In the figure I show here, you will see that my tablenote is far off to the left margin and wraps to several lines unnecessarily.

[image]

How do I get it to stop wrapping text this way and expand to \textwidth and/or the table width? I've tried many things without success.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, proquest]{uwthesis}

% Formatting packages
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

% Table packages:
% Multi-page tables and rotating:
    \usepackage{longtable,rotating}
% Allows use of three-part tables:
    \usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\begin{center}
    \scriptsize
    \def\arraystretch{1.2}
    \centering
    \caption{Statistical Evaluation \label{tab:Stats}}
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        Statistic   &  $V_{ed}/V_{n(prop1)}$  &  $V_{ed}/V_{n(prop3)}$ \\
        \hline          
        Count       &   9\tnote{*} & 13 \\
        \hline          
        Mean        &   \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}1.47 & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}1.35 \\
        \hline          
        Median      &   1.33 & 1.23 \\
        \hline          
        Min         &   1.12 & 1.04 \\
        \hline          
        Max         &   1.88 & 1.80 \\
        \hline          
        Std. Dev.   &   \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}0.292 & \cellcolor[HTML]       {C0C0C0}0.250    \\
        \hline          
        COV         &   0.199 & 0.184   \\
        \hline  
    \end{tabular}}
    \begin{tablenotes}
        \singlespacing
        \footnotesize
        \item[*] Blah Blah Blah Blah .Blah Blah Blah .Blah Blah Blah .Blah Blah Blah .Blah Blah Blah .
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\begin{threeparttable}` must appear  *before* `\caption` . And don't use the `center` environment inside a `table`: it adds superfluous vertical spacing. Prefer the command `\centering`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I just wanted to note that when I move the \begin{threeparttable} before \caption, I get errors. No issue ever appears with it after \caption though.

Comment: That's definitely abnormal: the first of the three parts is supposed to be the caption. Probably this is due to your non-standard class. That said, whatever works…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

Five suggestions: (1st and 2nd solve the problem, the rest is just a matter of style, but strongly recommended for formal documents).

1) Do not use `\resizebox` for tables unless strictly necessary. This produces inconsistent and unpredictable font sizes through the document.

2) Use `tabular*`, `tabularx` or `tabulary` if you want a table of some  specific width. The MWE below is made with `tabulary`.

3) Do not make tables with vertical lines and use as few horizontal lines as possible. Use `booktabs` package commands instead of `\hline`.

4) Use the `siunitx` package to align numbers with decimals.

5) Simplify your code:  `\begin{center} ... \centering ...\end{center}`   is redundant, the center environment add vertical spacing (that usually is undesirable in a float) and the code it is less readable.

```
\documentclass[11pt, proquest]{uwthesis}
% Formatting packages
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabulary}
\usepackage{siunitx}

% Table packages:
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{Statistical Evaluation \label{tab:Stats}}
    \begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabulary}{.5\linewidth}{LSS}
        \toprule
        Statistic   &  $V_{ed}/V_{n(prop1)}$  &  $V_{ed}/V_{n(prop3)}$ \\
        \midrule          
        Count       &   9\tnote{*} & 13 \\
        Mean        & {\cellcolor{lightgray}}  1.47
                    & {\cellcolor{lightgray}} 1.35 \\
        Median      &   1.33 & 1.23 \\
        Min         &   1.12 & 1.04 \\
        Max         &   1.88 & 1.80 \\
        Std. Dev.   & {\cellcolor{lightgray}} 0.292
                    & {\cellcolor{lightgray}} 0.250   \\
        COV         &   0.199 & 0.184   \\
        \bottomrule  
    \end{tabulary}
    \begin{tablenotes}
        \footnotesize
        \item[*] Blah Blah Blah Blah .Blah Blah Blah 
        .Blah Blah Blah .Blah Blah Blah .Blah Blah Blah .
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```